# Pandas slice using rows with column labels inside iteration gives future warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

This code works inside a `for` loop where 'i' is iterating it through the dataframe rows and occasionally this code line is used to reset all the rows preceeding row 'i', in column 'atr_Lts', so my cummulation calcs work as I require.

`cummax.loc[:i, 'atr_Lts'] = cummax.loc[cummax.index[i], 'atr_Lts']`

It works fine, but it is giving me the following warning, and I cannot find a better approach.

> FutureWarning: Slicing a positional slice with .loc is not supported,
> and will raise TypeError in a future version.  Use .loc with labels or
> .iloc with positions instead.

I need to be able to set all rows in column 'atr_Lts' up to the current iteration i, to the current 'atr_Lts' value. To get at that I need to use row selection (:i) and column label ('atr_Lts') but according to the warning I can not combine the approach.

In many searches this was the recommended method, but is going to be obselete so wondered what the better approach is.

**EDIT: copy of example cummax dataframe print**

```
Date          Close       atr     atr_Lts     atr_Sts       atrts
2022-02-23  421.950012       NaN  371.614245  413.538855  413.538855
2022-02-24  428.299988       NaN  371.614245  413.538855  413.538855
2022-02-25  437.750000       NaN  371.614245  413.538855  413.538855
2022-02-28  436.630005       NaN  371.614245  413.538855  413.538855
2022-03-01  429.980011       NaN  371.614245  413.538855  413.538855
```

this is the print(cummax.info())

```
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------   --------------  -----
 0   Close    125 non-null    float64
 1   atr      112 non-null    float64
 2   atr_Lts  125 non-null    float64
 3   atr_Sts  112 non-null    float64
 4   atrts    112 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(5)
```

Comment: Try putting square bracket for atr_Lts

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I tried that but if I only put them round the first 'atr_Lts' I get the same error and if i add them to the second 'atr_Lts' I get this error ```ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (17,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (17,1)``` but it is the first part creating the message, not the second.

Comment: could you please add a sample of your data as text? I just tried your syntax on a random df here on my side and I didn't get the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is raised because `.loc` requires a **label based index**, you passed and **integer based index**: `.loc[:i, <some columns>]` (`i` is an int), therefore causing pandas to be confused.

To make this warning go away, you can either try:

- Ignore the warnings using the `warnings` module.
- Typing this instead: `cummax.iloc[:i].loc[:, 'atr_Lts'] = ...`.